# How insert view (child) into div of parent layout? Vaadin 10 / Flow

Tags: java, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I have a component implementing **RouterLayout** like this:

```
@Tag("side-menu")
@HtmlImport(value = "src/components/side-menu.html")
public class SideMenu extends PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel> implements RouterLayout {

    @Id("menu")
    private PaperListBox listBox = new PaperListBox();

    public SideMenu() {

        listBox.addMenu(new PaperItem("tutorial", TutorialView.class));
        listBox.addMenu(new PaperItem("icons", IconsView.class));

    }
}
```

I route a view child of the parent layout

```
@Route(value=IconsView.VIEW_ROUTE, layout = SideMenu.class)
public class IconsView extends Div {

    public static final String VIEW_ROUTE = "icons";

    public IconsView() {
        add(new Label("ICONS VIEW"));
    }

}
```

But the result overwrote all the content of **side-menu.html** file.

**side-menu.html** template base format

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id=contenido><!-- I want to show here my view Icons --></div>
</side-menu>
```

But the result it's

```
<side-menu>
    <div>
       <label>ICONOS VIEW</label>
    </div>
</side-menu>
```

The expected result is:

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id=contenido>
       <div>
          <label>ICONOS VIEW</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</side-menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-components-in-slot.html) said this:

> You can add child components to templates using the `Component` or
>   `Element` API, but because PolymerTemplate uses the shadow DOM **the
>   shadow tree is rendered instead of the elements children** that are in
>   the light DOM.
>
> This means that the template needs to have a `<slot></slot>` to mark
>   the place where the light DOM elements should be rendered.

I found a solution for this composite layout:

I only needed to be modified my template **side-menu.html** and add a `<slot>` tag like this:

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <slot></slot>
</side-menu>
```

And then when my view is loaded, it's rendered into the `<slot>` tag into the template

Comment: What if I only use Vaadin Flow to build my view, with no @HtmlImport or @Tag? How can I define a slot then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that since you have bare template without functionality and databinding and custom template model, the server side is not aware of its contents. Thus Div.add() thinks it as empty div and overwrites its content.

One approach in your case would be to modify the content via Element API, which could be something like:

```
public IconsView() {
    label = new Label("ICONS VIEW");
    getElement().appendChild(label.getElement());
}
```

See API spec

https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-core/10.0.0.rc5/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Node.html#appendChild-com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element...-

Another approach would be to extend the html template to be fully functional polymer element

There is more about that e.g. here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-list-bindings.html